# How to correctly perform wildcard search on a field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

My `sData.Name` mapping looks as below:

```
{
    "abc_history": {
        "mappings": {
            "abc-data-type": {
                "sData.Name": {
                    "full_name": "sData.Name",
                    "mapping": {
                        "Name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `sData.startDate` mapping looks as below

```
{
    "abc_history": {
        "mappings": {
            "abc-data-type": {
                "sData.startDate": {
                    "full_name": "sData.startDate",
                    "mapping": {
                        "startDate": {
                            "type": "date"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to perform a wildcard search on `sData.Name` and used following query:

```
{
  "from": 0, 
  "size": 20, 
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must":[
              {"range": {"requestDate": { "gte": "2019-10-01T08:00:00.000Z" }}},
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "sData.Name": "*Scream*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "sort": [
          { "requestDate": {"order": "desc"}}
        ]
}
```

The above query is returning empty response. How should I modify my query so that I can perform `wildcard search` on `sData.Name`?

Response from `http://{serverhost}:{port}/abc_history/_search` looks as below:

```
{
  "took": 181,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "abc_history",
        "_type": "abc-data-type",
        "_id": "5e29cbb7965809fe6cb22a7b",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "sData": [
            {
              "status": "ASSIGNED",
              "Name": "CloudView abcmission Automation Support",
              startDate : "2020-01-26T20:12:57.091Z"

            },
            {
              "status": "RESOLVED",
              "Name": "DSE - Tools Engineering",
              startDate : "2020-01-27T20:12:57.091Z" 
            },
            {
              "status": "CLOSED",
              "Name": "abcmission Orchestration",
              startDate : "2020-01-29T20:12:57.091Z"
            },
            {
              "status": "ASSIGNED",
              "Name": "CloudView abcmission Automation Support",
              startDate : "2020-01-29T20:19:29.687Z"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1579797431366
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am mainly concerned about querying `sData.Name`. I want to perform search only in the last array element. So in my case I want to search only `sData[3].Name` In other words the keyword `DSE` should be searched within `"Name": "CloudView abcmission Automation Support"` only

Answer (score 1):

I try to create the index by your input. Try to use

```
"wildcard": {
    "sData.Name.keyword": {
    "wildcard": "*DSE*",
        "boost": 1
    }
}
```

The full query is:

```
PUT /abc_history
{
  "mappings": {
    "abc-data-type": {
      "properties": {
        "sData": {
          "properties": {
            "status": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "Name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword",
                          "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


GET /abc_history/_search
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "wildcard": {
                                    "sData.Name.keyword": {
                                        "wildcard": "*DSE*",
                                        "boost": 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    }
}
```

It may

```
GET /abc_history/_search
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "wildcard": {
                                    "sData.Name": {
                                        "wildcard": "*ddd*",
                                        "boost": 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "sData.startDate": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is not working and still giving an empty result

Comment: Please paste  your  index creating script here.

Comment: Do you mean the script that is used to create the `abc_history` index? I only have the `_search` query

Comment: Do you have some query console like kibana?

Comment: No we don't have query console. I am able to use `postman` to run queries such as `_search` and `_mappings`

Comment: http://{serverhost}:{port}/abc_history  to get the script and paste it in your question. For example:
http://localhost:9200/abc_history  to get the script.

Comment: I have pasted the script in my question

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. the above query seems to be working but I want to search in the last array element. So in my case I want to search only `sData[3].Name` In other words the keyword `*DSE*` should be searched within `"Name": "CloudView abcmission Automation Support"` only

Comment: I have updated my question as well. Again thanks for your help!!

Comment: I do not think there has solution based on your index and requirement.   These is no way to locate the last element in your array.   You need to consider add some other indicator to such some timestamp in your sData object.

Comment: Can you please help me understand what you mean by placing some other indicator in my sData object?

Comment: Add a new field in sData object. for example: {
              "status": "ASSIGNED",
              "Name": "CloudView abcmission Automation Support",
              "index": 3
            }.  if you have index filed in sData object, you could add another query condition to filter the last element out.

Comment: Thanks! Can you let me know the api to update the sData object with new `index field`? Also, will this delete existing data within index?

Comment: So far, I do not know there is this kind of API to update the array index. I just gave you a thought that you could add your specific filed to be filtered out.

Comment: I am able to add additional field `startDate : "2020-01-28T20:12:57.091Z"` in the `sData` object. Can you help modifying the query so that it filters out the last `sData` element based upon the `startDate`? I have also updated my question accordingly

Comment: Also no way,  startDate is not a known value.

Comment: `startDate` is known value and is of `date` type. I have added mapping for `startDate` in my question. Also, `startDate` is in ascending order so there should be a way to sort it out and find the last `sData` element

Comment: If the condition is  "startDate = "2020-01-29T20:19:29.687Z". it may work.

Comment: Yeah, but first we do `desc sort` on `sData.startDate` to find out the last date value. Can you help updating the query accordingly?